# How to create loop sequence?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am trying to create a script that will be getting one variable from user and should print a pyramid as below:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

I used this script but it shows me numbers:

```
for i in {1..5}

do

a=${a}${i}

echo ${a}

done
```

the output:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

How can I insert "*" sign instead of numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply append the `*` character to the `a` variable, instead of the loop counter:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
  a+='*'
  echo "${a}"
done
```

Note that `a="${a}*"` instead of `a+='*'` works just as well, but I think the `+=` version is neater/clearer.

If you want to do this with a while loop instead, you could do something like this:

```
while (( "${#a}" < 5 )); do
  a+='*'
  echo "$a"
done
```

`${#a}` expands to the length of the string in the `a` variable.

Note that both of the above code snippets (as well as the code in the question) assume that the `a` var is empty or not set at the start of the snippet.  If this is not the case, then you'll need to reinitialize it first:

```
a=
```

I am assuming you are using the bash shell.  [Here is the full manual.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)  Here is the [section on looping constructs.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs)

Answer (score 5):

[Digital Trauma](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/34061/digital-trauma)'s answer is more efficient in this case, but just for completeness' sake you could use the traditional shell method of repeating characters using `printf`:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
  printf "%${i}s\n"
done | sed 's/ /*/g'
```

This uses `printf` to output as many spaces as required, then `sed` to replace the spaces with the character we really want.

As pointed out by [Digital Trauma](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/34061/digital-trauma) and [Janis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/102438/janis), you can store the result of `printf` in a variable and use the shell's substring replacement to avoid using `sed` (at the cost of spawning lots of subshells in many cases):

```
for i in {1..5}
do
  a=$(printf "%${i}s")
  echo "${a// /*}"
done
```

The quotes are necessary with `echo` here to avoid the shell interpreting the `*` characters. Furthermore, with `echo` the `\n` is no longer necessary.

As pointed out by [kojiro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5377/kojiro), `tr` is more suited to replacing single characters than `sed`:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
  printf "%${i}s\n"
done | tr ' ' '*'
```

(But the `sed` variant allows repeating text of any length.)

Comment: or `printf -va "%${i}s"; echo "${a// /*}"` to remove the need to spawn `sed` on each iteration of the loop.  Or even better put the `| sed 's/ /*/g'` after the `done`.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. `printf -va` doesn't seem particularly portable so I'll go with the single `sed`.

Comment: I never saw this command but I like it! thank you! Do you have a website where I can find explanation for every sign in this script?

Comment: For `printf`, you should find documentation in the [`bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html); there's also the [`printf(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) and [`printf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) manpages. For `sed`, read the [`sed(1)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html).

Comment: @Invoker and if you want to learn `sed`, here's another way `sed -n -e ':x' -e 's/^/*/;p;/.\{5\}/q' -e 'bx' <<< ''`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, @Stephen Kitt; Note, you don't need `printf -va` to achieve what's behind the idea; you could use: `a=$(printf "%*s\n" "$i" "") ;   echo "${a// /*}"`.

Comment: @Janis yes, process substitution also works and is probably more portable.  The advantage with the `-v` option is that there is not need to spawn a subshell for every iteration of the loop, which of course is not a big deal for 5 iterations, but adds up with large numbers of iterations.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma; ITYM *"Command Substitution"*. But note that not all shells invoke an unnecessary subshell with a command substitution.

Comment: @Janis Yes, command substitution.  Sorry.

Comment: @Janis - that command substitution is a pretty awful solution in any shell which is not `ksh93`. `sed` should definitely be preferred in almost every case.

Comment: StephenKitt - my tests show that your first suggestion actually outperforms @DigitalTrauma's answer after all. And I think your `printf -va` would likely do far better performance-wise than did the subshell. In fact, that's a *very* good idea - can it do more than a single variable per call? If so, it could be pretty good.

Comment: @mikeserv; I'd always avoid additional processes - specifically `sed` which should IMO just be used for simple substitutions where no other performant means exist - if I can do it in shell efficiently. - Yes, `ksh` is in many respects better than many other shells where performance (or features) is an issue.

Comment: @Janis - Avoiding additional processes not worth their exec time should usually be done, but overloading a single process is likewise a mistake. UNIX systems are timesharing systems - pipelines make concurrency possible. If you can call up one process to handle a stream of output from another process *concurrently* to the generation of said stream, why wouldn't you? Regarding `sed` - in my experience when it can be usefully applied there are very few other equally performant options. For example, I also ran some of my tests on 100000 char strings. `sed` did it in 8 secs, `awk` 45.

Comment: @mikeserv That will teach me to talk about efficiency without actually measuring... I agree that the `printf -v` variant is nice, but it's `bash`-specific.

Comment: @StephenKitt - probably true, but is it any less portable than `${a// /}` or whatever? I haven't tested it, but I'd be willing to bet the `printf` thing could be quicker.

Comment: @mikeserv I agree it should be quicker, but it is less portable; `${a// /}` is supported by more shells than `printf -v`.

Comment: @mikeserv; Not sure why you mention in your comment a comparison of `sed` and `awk` (with some test case that I don't even see). - My comment was about avoiding a `sed` process that was not necessary since it could be done with standard shell idioms. And the whole point was anyway only how to avoid a non-standard `printf -v` (which is, e.g., not supported by `ksh`). And of course no one minds a single `sed` process; but folks learn to wrongly "extend" such patterns and use `sed` (etc.) for replacements in strings inside loops; I'm sure you certainly have seen a lot such code as well.

Comment: @Janis - the test case is in my answer to this question. But what is the point of avoiding the process - is it a ulimit thing or is it a performance thing? If it is a performance thing, then advice given to perform text manipulations in the shell as opposed to doing so with a highly-specialized tool is probably misguided. Yes - doing `for f do printf %s\\n "$f" | sed 's/edit something//'; done` is a *horrible* practice. But that's not what is recommended here, instead Stepehen recommends the *good* way: `for f do printf %s\\n "$f"; done | sed 's/edit all of the things//'`.

Comment: @mikeserv; I think your question and all related considerations are already addressed in my previous comment. - Given what you wrote I don't think our POVs are significantly differing.

Comment: @Janis - looking at it again - and lending a little more emphasis to the *And the whole point was* sentence, and I think maybe you're right.

Answer (score 4):

POSIXly:

```
$ n=5 awk 'BEGIN{OFS="*";for(i=2;i<=ENVIRON["n"]+1;i++){$i="";print}}'
```

Comment: Interesting :) +1 for making me more *posixly* aware and *setting awk fields* aware.

Comment: Rerhaps `OFS="*"` would be (technically) better before the `for` loop. -- and I think `-v  assignment`  is POSIX-ly correct; so no need for `ENVIRON`, though it is interesting to see it in use.

Comment: @Peter.O: Good point. If you can read deleted post, see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208058/38906)

Comment: A very clever solution, +1! `ENVIRON` is indeed useful, but I don't really see the point here. Why not just `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="*";for(i=2;i<=6;i++){$i="";print}}'`?

Comment: @terdon: It's better to give custom parameter outside your script, you can custom it. Something like `n=10 awk -f script.awk`.

Answer (score 2):

First, here are some timed comparisons of some other solutions offered:

```
time \
    bash -c '
        for i in {1..1000}
        do    printf "%0${i}s\n"
        done| sed "y/ /*/"
'   >/dev/null

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.023s
sys     0m0.000s
```

That's not bad, though I did add a slight optimization by using a `y/ /*/` translation expression rather than a `s/ /*/g` regular expression substitution statement.

```
time \
     bash -c '
     for i in {1..1000}
     do    a=$(printf "%0${i}s")
           echo "${a// /*}"
     done
'    >/dev/null

real    0m1.337s
user    0m0.723s
sys     0m0.187s
```

Wow. That's terrible.

Here's one which I would suggest you use if you were really hell-bent on a shell-only solution. The advantage to this over the other tested is that, in the first place, it doesn't need to set two variables - only one is ever set and that is `$IFS` and that is only once. It also does not fork a child shell per iteration - which is generally *not* a good idea.

It relies on the substitution mechanism in `$*` for fields in `$@`. So it just adds a new null positional for each iteration. Notice also that it avoids the `for {1..1000}` wasteful brace expansion.

```
time \
    bash -c '
        IFS=\*; set ""
        until [ "$#" -gt 1001 ]
        do    set "" "$@"
              echo  "$*"
        done
'   >/dev/null

real    0m0.755s
user    0m0.753s
sys     0m0.000s
```

While it is twice as fast as the other shell-only solution, it is still pretty damn terrible.

This is a little better - it goes the other way. Rather than expanding `"$@"` to get the values it wants, it builds it exponentially, and trims it incrementally:

```
time \
    bash -c '
        set \*;n=0 IFS=
        until [ "$#" -gt 512 ]
        do    set "$@" "$@"
              shift "$(($#>1000?24:0))"
              until [ "$n" -eq "$#" ]
              do    printf %."$((n+=1))s\n" "$*"
        done; done
'   >/dev/null

real    0m0.158s
user    0m0.157s
sys     0m0.020s
```

To beat my own shell-only suggestion out by, well, a lot, *(at least with `bash` - `dash` doing the above and `bash` doing the below are neck and neck)*:

```
time \
    bash -c 'a=
        for i in {1..1000}
        do    a+=\*
              echo "$a"
        done
'   >/dev/null

real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Which is encouraging - it would appear `bash` optimizes the `a+=` form to *actually* do an append rather than a complete re-eval/re-assign. Anyway, the `sed` still beats it.

The `sed` above does not beat `awk`, though:

```
time \
    bash -c '
        n=1000 \
        awk "BEGIN{OFS=\"*\";for(i=2;i<=ENVIRON[\"n\"]+1;i++){\$i=\"\";print}}"
'   >/dev/null

real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.000s
```

...which is the fastest yet.

But none beat another `sed` which does basically what my `nstars` function *(you'll find it below)* would do if you did `nstars 1000`:

```
time \
    bash -c '
        printf %01000s |
        sed -ne "H;x;:loop
             s/\(\n\)./*1/
             P;//t loop"
'   >/dev/null

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.003s
```

...which is the fastest yet. *(when run with `time nstars 1000 >/dev/null` the **real** result was **.006s**)*. There's more on it below.

Another POSIX solution:

```
echo Type some stuff:
sed -ne 'H;x;:loop
    s/\(\n\)./*\1/
    P;//!q;t loop'
```

Paste the above directly into your terminal, enter any string and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will see a pyramid of `*`s, one line for each character you entered. A 3-character string will give three lines, a 4-character one will print 4 etc.

`sed` is perfectly capable of reading tty input and manipulating it however you like. In this case it reads a line from the user, puts a `\n`ewline at the head of the string read in, and then recursively replaces the `\n`ewline and the character immediately following it with a `*` and the `\n`ewline again, all the while `P`rinting only up to the `\n`ewline each time.

As it does so, pattern space actually looks like this *(I just swapped the `P`rint command for a `l`ook)*:

```
here's some stuff
*\nere's some stuff$
**\nre's some stuff$
***\ne's some stuff$
****\n's some stuff$
*****\ns some stuff$
******\n some stuff$
*******\nsome stuff$
********\nome stuff$
*********\nme stuff$
**********\ne stuff$
***********\n stuff$
************\nstuff$
*************\ntuff$
**************\nuff$
***************\nff$
****************\nf$
*****************\n$
```

The top line was my input. With the `P`, though:

```
here's some stuff
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
***********
************
*************
**************
***************
****************
*****************
```

If you want to stop it at 5, for example, you can add a `/.\{5\}\n/` test, like this:

```
echo Type some stuff:
sed -ne 'H;x;:loop
    s/\(\n\)./*\1/
    P;//!q;/.\{5\}\n/q
    t loop'
```

You can generate the strings in the same way:

```
nstars()(  n=${1##*[!0-9]*}
           shift  "$((!!n))" 
           if   [ -n "${n:-$1}" ]
           then printf %0"$n"s "$*"
           else [ -t 0 ] &&
                echo Type some stuff: >&0
                head -n 1
           fi | sed -ne 'H;x;:loop
                     s/\(\n\)./*\1/
                     P;//t loop'
)
```

There, with that you can give a numeric first argument and `sed` will print the stars recursively up to your count, or you can give one or more string arguments and `sed` will print the stars for all chars in the string, or you can run it on a terminal and it will prompt for one line of input and print chars for that, or it will handle any other file input without prompting.

```
{   nstars 3
    nstars three
    echo 3please | nstars
    nstars
}
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
*
**
***
*
**
***
****
*****
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
Type some stuff:
ok
*
**
```

Comment: I particularly like the `IFS=\*` version, though it needs `set "";` before the `until` loop to prevent a leading blank line. +1

Comment: @Peter.O - well, it doesn't here - there are no positionals. What blank line? Oh wait - good point - there is no separator between `''` and nothing - none is needed when `$# == 1`. The same script with `dash -c`, by the way, works in *.1s real* - so only perhaps 1 or 1.5 orders of magnitude slower than the `sed`/`awk` variants.

Comment: @Peter.O - I fixed it, and added one more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` and its `s/regexp/replacement/flags` command.

```bash
seq 10 |sed 's/.*/printf "*%.0s" {1..&}/e'
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

- The *flag* `e` says that if substitution was made, the command that is found (in pattern space) is executed and pattern space is replaced with its output. See the [GNU *sed* manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command).
- The command `printf "STRING%.0s" {1..7}` print *STRING* seven times. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/11407924).
- The `&` inside *replacement* in `s/regexp/replacement/e`, reference the whole matched portion of the pattern space. In this case, each number in turn, in the sequence given by `seq`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
$ max=5 perl -E 'say "*" x ++$c while $c <= $ENV{max}'
*
**
***
****
*****
```